# Master page form element with content page form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, forms

Here is the scenario I already have the form element in the master page and now in the content page I used the multiple file upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ but this is working with the form submit action and I have already form element in the master page. So how could I worked with the 2 nested form element?

Below is the code snippet of the master page and content page. This multiple upload plug in is only working with the form and I could not achieve this with the master page. Please help to get it resolved.

**Master Page**

```
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Content Page**

```
  <form id="fileupload" action="server/dotnet/Default.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
           <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="Files" id="Files" runat="server" />
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" runat="server">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I there any specific help then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As form is `runat` `server` so we can change it on content page.

On your content page page_load you can write

```
 Form.Action="server/dotnet/Default.aspx";
```

And by default in asp.net the method is `Post`.

Comment: Hi Shekhar so what should I do? But I already have the form in the content page also. There are 2 form tag one is in master and another is in content

Comment: you can not have two form tag. just change the Action on your content page.

Comment: @Shekhar If I set this in the content page load then there are some other buttons on the left pane of the master page so when I click on that then that will redirected to this default.aspx page. I don't want that I want only content page's button submit use the form action and redirected to default.aspx page.